# Print line numbers starting at zero using awk

Tags: awk

Can anyone tell me how to print line numbers including zero using awk?

Here is my input file [stackfile2.txt](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=73C0B2AE8E459B12!138&authkey=!AO1vZBZKP4QnBFE&ithint=file%2ctxt)

when I run the below awk command I get [actual_output.txt](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=73C0B2AE8E459B12!139&authkey=!AO1vZBZKP4QnBFE&ithint=file%2ctxt)

```
awk '{print NR,$0}' stackfile2.txt | tr " ", "," > actual_output.txt
```

whereas my expected output is [file.txt](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=73C0B2AE8E459B12!143&authkey=!AON7KfT-xDHtJ1g&ithint=file%2ctxt)

How do I print the line numbers starting with zero (0)?

Comment: Isn't it `awk '{print NR-1,$0}'`?

Comment: @user790049, don't make us chase links to find out what the problem is. Show a small sample input and tell us what you want the output to look like. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry about that will take care from next time onwards

Comment: The links to the files are broken. Could you [edit] the question to include some proper [mcve]?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

NR starts at 1, so use

```
awk '{print NR-1 "," $0}'
```

Comment: It might be nicer to set the output field separator to the comma: `awk -v OFS="," '{print NR-1, $0}' file`.

Comment: If you're looking for custom start value and other customizations, look at the answer  based on `nl` below.

Answer (score 18):

Using awk.

i starts at 0, `i++` will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

```
awk '{print i++ "," $0}' file
```

Comment: + for one character shorter than `NR-1` You could also have used `awk '{print i++,$0}' OFS=, file` but this would be longer.

Comment: @Jotne When out for golfing, `awk '$0=i++","$0'` beats it ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Another option besides awk is [nl](https://ss64.com/bash/nl.html) which allows for options `-v` for setting starting value and `-n <lf,rf,rz>` for left, right and right with leading zeros justified. You can also include `-s` for a field separator such as `-s ","` for comma separation between line numbers and your data.

In a Unix environment, this can be done as

```
cat <infile> | ...other stuff... | nl -v 0 -n rz
```

or simply

```
nl -v 0 -n rz <infile>
```

Example:

```
echo "Here 
are
some 
words" > words.txt
```

`cat words.txt | nl -v 0 -n rz`

Out:

```
000000      Here
000001      are
000002      some
000003      words
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option, you can try this:

```
perl -ne 'printf "%s,$_" , $.-1' file
```

`$_` is the line
`$.` is the line number