# System.out.print . How do you get the printed output to be numbered? (Java)

Tags: java, output, system.out

So assuming I am printing out a huge record of 500 staff members. And upon printing out the record I would like it to look something like:

```
   1. Matthew J. $USD 28.404
   2. Donna M. $USD 43.254
   3. Jordan D. $USD 15.532
   4.
   5. 
   6.
   7. and so on......
```

However...with the normal printout command it looks like:

```
System.out.println();
```

My output :

```
   Matthew J. $USD 28.404
   Donna M. $USD 43.254
   Jordan D. $USD 15.532



   and so on......
```

EDIT: So how do I get the output to have each line numbered?

**LATER EDIT**:

My System.out.print is printing out info out of a list (from a JSON, all that is solved thx to Prasad Khode) here is my code:

```
for (Manager iterator : managersList) {

    System.out.println(iterator.getName() + " - " + iterator.getSalary());
}
```

This prints out

```
Name - Salary
```

How can I make it print:

```
1. Name - Salary
2. Name - Salary
```

and so on.
A solution will be so much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can increment an integer and print it, followed by a period and a space.

Comment: So are you asking how to print those numbers `1, 2, 3...`?

Comment: Give me the code you use for printing it, I give you code doing what you want :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. How do I add those numbers before each ouput line. Edited the question. Terribly sorry if it seems vague.

Comment: A `System.out.print(++line + ". " );` executed preceding your println is all you need. Assuming, of course, that the 500 are printed in a *loop*. If not, say so.

Comment: I added my real issue in the thread. Sorry for not posting it earlier. @libik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 1;
while(something) {
    println(i + "." + SomeName);
    i++
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Edited question. Again I apologize for not explaining the issue correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using a for loop to print the records then you can use

```
System.out.println((i+1)+". "+ record[i]);
```

Comment: Edited question. Again I apologize for not explaining the issue correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `System.out.println()` so that it outputs line numbers is not an easy task. You could create a new PrintStream subclass (thats what `out` is), override all the appropriate methods in PrintStream so that `println(boolean)`, and `println(char)` and `println(long)` and so on all print out the line number at the start (which is maintained in the class itself). Then, create it pointing to `System.out` and somehow reattach `System.out` to this PrintStream.  Its not impossible, and could be a worthy undertaking for someone wanting to mess around in the guts of System, but there are a *number* of easier ways to do this.

First off, consider just printing the entire stream out and then pipe it through [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752043/289086) or some such program.  Much easier and doesn't mess around with things.

Assuming you do want to get into the "this needs to be the output from Java", lets just create a wrapper class.

```
package com.michaelt.so.outwrapper;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Wrapper {
    static PrintStream out = System.out;
    static int lineNum = 1;

    static void println(String arg) {
        out.println((lineNum++) + ". " + arg);
    }

    static void printlnFancy(String arg) {
        out.printf("%3d. %s\n", lineNum++, arg);
    }
}
```

and then use that:

```
package com.michaelt.so.outwrapper;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'f'; c++) {
            Wrapper.println(""+c); // I just want a string
        }

        for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'F'; c++) {
            Wrapper.printlnFancy(""+c);
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints out:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
6. f
  7. A
  8. B
  9. C
 10. D
 11. E
 12. F
```

I'm not saying this is a good thing.  And it involves changing all your `System.out.println()` to the Wrapper class... but it doesn't actually mess with `System.out` which could lead to surprising things.

Comment: I solved my issue with @RobinGenolet 's solution . However you took a lot of time and effort in posting this very elaborate answer so thank you for that.

Comment: Amazing advice.  I actually created the Wrapper class in another project just to check how it works. However it takes less time using the above approved solution. And in the words of the greatest Benjamin Franklin "Time is money." . I truly appreciate the time and effort you put in writing this answer. Thanks again.